# How to monitor bluetooth device connectivity status in xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms

Can someone guide me on how to monitor the connection status of Bluetooth device?
When the device is disconnected I need the notification. Please guide. Does Bluetooth LE plugin work for the normal Bluetooth?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Shiny is one of the more commonly used plugin, which is a Xamarin Framework for Backgrounding & Device Hardware Services.

First you should read the [README.md](https://github.com/shinyorg/shiny/blob/master/readme.md) file of this plugin. They provides two interfaces, `IBluetoothLE` is helping you to access the Bluetooth status and related things and the `IAdapter` is for handling the device and communicate with it.

The following information should be helpful for you to understand the plugin.

```
[IBluetoothLE].StateChanged => To know the Bluetooth status, like its off/on
[IAdapter].DeviceDiscovered => This will trigger when any device is discovered
[IAdapter].ConnectToDeviceAsync => For connecting with a device
[IAdapter].GetServicesAsync => To read the Bluetooth device service (The service is 
providing the characteristic to read and write the query between connected device)
[service].GetCharacteristicsAsync => To get the characteristics from the selected 
service
[characteristic].ReadAsync => Read the data from the device
[characteristic].WriteAsync => Write the data to the device
[characteristic].ValueUpdated => This will trigger when the data through from the 
device
[characteristic].StartUpdatesAsync => Start to get the notifying the value updates
```

And there are samples about almost every single function point within Shiny.
https://github.com/shinyorg/shinysamples

For more details, you can check: https://shinydocs.azurewebsites.net/docs/ble/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Shiny](https://github.com/shinyorg/shiny).
You will be able to get the connected devices and get status changes:

https://shinydocs.azurewebsites.net/docs/ble/central/centralmanager